# Get Object Property Description using Reflection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to get the object description using reflection. I can get the name, value, etc... but not the description like in .net.

For example the description for .Text is "Gets or sets the text associated with this control."

I thought maybe using MethodInfo, but does not give the description.

```
    Dim MethodObj As MethodInfo
    Console.WriteLine("Methods:")
    For Each MethodObj In GetType(TextBox).GetMethods()
        Debug.Print(MethodObj.Name & " " & MethodObj.ReturnType.ToString())
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this description via reflection, because it is not compiled into the assembly. During compilation an [XML documentation file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx) is generated that contains this description. You need to parse this XML file to get the description. However, you don't always have this file, because it is not required to execute the assembly.

Comment: Reason i'm asking is because i built a text editor for creating simple logic in an application and wanted to provide more than just the property name. I guess I'll have to add description to database and pull it from there.

Comment: @tmax: Another possibility would be to use the [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) on your properties. This can be retrieved via reflection.

Comment: Actually [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) worked. The description is a little different. but it will work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the description as shown in MSDN, that's not part of the metadata shipped with the executable code. If you've got the XML documentation to go alongside the assembly, you could try to find the right method in that - but in most cases I wouldn't expect it to be available.

Comment: Thanks guys, saves me some time researching. I think I will put descriptions in db. this way it will be more stable. Besides i'm only giving them limited properties not the enire collection.